# Return the value of each element in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do this only using javascript? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic JavaScript...

```
var arr = document.forms[0].elements;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var el = arr[i];
  // do something with it.
  console.log(el.value) // or similar
}
```

Comment: Could also note that the form can be accessed by name: `document.forms['formName'].elements'`

Comment: @RobG: Indeed it can, but this method is completely portable and requires no knowledge of the page and/or form

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

It gives back a standard URL-encoded string.  However the nice thing is that it encapsulates getting the values of all of the different types of form elements.

Comment: I would normally downvote the use of jQuery when the question says `only using Javascript`, but I don't think the OP knows the difference :)

Comment: The requirements were vague enough, I figured jQuery-based solutions were reasonable :)

Comment: jQuery wasn't asked for, nor was serialisation, and there already is a good solution. But no downvote, I'm not *that* mean. :-)

Comment: If you go down the route of "pure JavaScript" - you can't do what OP asks for as JavaScript itself does not include DOM objects... JQuery looks as pure JavaScript as it can get in browser - no C#, VBScript, PHP, LISP,... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/serialize/). These guys built something that only uses pure JS and serializes a form.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns all form elements as in an associative array. It also returns all values for multiple input elements that are selected.

```
        function getFormVals(form) {
            var values = [];
            for(var i = 0, len = form.elements.length; i < len; i++) {
                var input = form.elements[i];
                switch (input.type.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        values[input.name] = values[input.name] || [];
                        if (input.checked) {
                            values[input.name].push(input.value);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "radio":
                        values[input.name] = values[input.name] || "";
                        if (input.checked) {
                            values[input.name] = input.value;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "select-multiple":
                        values[input.name] = values[input.name] || [];
                        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (input[i].selected) {
                                values[input.name].push(input[i].value);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        values[input.name] = input.value;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

usage could be:

```
<form onsubmit="var vals = getFormVals(this); alert(vals['myinput']);" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="myinput" value="ckbx1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="myinput" value="ckbx2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```